How to use $\{x, y\}$ etc in ZFC
ZFC has axioms that assert the existence of sets that satisfy certain conditions.
For example, the axiom of pairing
$$\forall A\forall B \exists C\forall D(D\in C\Leftrightarrow (D=A\vee D=B))$$
asserts the existence of $\{A, B\}$.
The question is, how to interpret a proposition which contains, for example, $\{x,y\}$ into a ZFC sentence?
Example problem: $$\forall A\forall B\exists x(x\in \{A, B\})$$
My attempt 1: $$\forall A\forall B\color{red}{\forall} C(\forall D(D\in C\Leftrightarrow (D=A\vee D=B))\Rightarrow \exists x(x\in C))$$
My attempt 2: $$\forall A\forall B(\color{red}{\exists} C\forall D(D\in C\Leftrightarrow (D=A\vee D=B))\Rightarrow \exists x(x\in C))$$

Your attempt 2 should use $\land$ instead of $\Rightarrow$; otherwise it holds vacuously, by choosing a set $C$ that is not the pair ${A, B}$. Both attempts are then valid translations of your original proposition.

Your attempt 1 is correct. There’s something wrong with the parentheses in attempt 2 (if $\exists C$ only refers to the $\forall D$ term, then $x \in C$ in the later term makes no sense). Also, in attempt 2, you should have used $\wedge$ instead of $\Rightarrow$. The corrected version of attempt 2 should be,$$\forall A\forall B\exists C(\forall D(D \in C \Leftrightarrow (D=A \vee D=B))\wedge\exists x(x \in C))$$This corrected version will also be right, and in fact equivalent to attempt 1 under ZFC. (Though, personally, I think 1 makes better sense.)

(I find 1 making better sense to me mostly because 2 (or rather, the corrected version of it), also asserts the axiom of pairing in it. In fact, if we remove the axiom of pairing from ZFC, then attempt 2 is exactly equivalent to axiom of pairing, while attempt 1 does not assert the axiom of pairing as a consequence - in fact, attempt 1 is a tautology.)

@DavidGao I am a bit confused. Could you please explain how to prove that 1 and 2 are equivalent?

@user1361001 A bit boringly, both are true in ZFC, so they are equivalent. A more illuminating explanation is to just translate these into natural language: 1 just says for any $C$ satisfying the defining condition of ${A,B}$ (namely, something is an element of $C$ iff it is either $A$ or $B$), $C$ has an element, while 2 says there exists a $C$ satisfying the defining condition of ${A,B}$ and also has an element. ZFC proves there exists a unique $C$ satisfying the defining condition of ${A,B}$, so the equivalence follows.

@user1361001 Of course this needs that ZFC proves there is a unique $C$ satisfying the defining condition of ${A,B}$. So if you remove either axiom of extensionality or axiom of pairing, the above argument will no longer work.
